# Wrapfigure next to Center environment

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure, wrap, beamerposter

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.5]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \makebox[0.95\linewidth][c]{
            \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    1
                \end{center}
                \begin{center}
                    2
                \end{center}
                \begin{center}
                    3
                \end{center}
                AAA
                \begin{center}
                    Nanophysics
                \end{center}
                BBB
                \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{./images/graphen}
                \end{wrapfigure}
                \textbf{Graphene and carbon nanotubes} are materials with extraordinary mechanical and electronic properties. High electron conductivity, linear energy dispersion and relatively long spin relaxation time make them good candidates for replacing silicon in low power electronics and spintronics.
                Our research focuses on spin-orbit interaction in carbon-based systems induced by adatoms, substrate or external fields. Starting from first principle calculations we develop realistic theoretical models describing the underlying physics.
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want to wrap text around `graphen`. Above code does not produce a good result. However, if you comment out inner `center` like so:

```
%\begin{center}
    Nanophysics
%\end{center}
```

it starts to work as expected.

Any ideas what's going on?

EDIT:

samcarter provided a valid workaround. Nonetheless, if there are more `\begin{center}...\end{center}` blocks (like the ones I added above Nanophysics part) it's becoming a problem to rewrite all of them.

Also, out of pure curiosity, maybe someone knows what exactly is the **cause** of such behaviour?

Comment: wrapfig documentation is very short but the one thing that it does document is that it must not be used near lists. `center` like most latex display environments, is a list (a one item list in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.5]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \makebox[0.95\linewidth][c]{
            \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                AAA

                \makebox[\textwidth][c]{Nanophysics}

                BBB

                \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}
                \end{wrapfigure}
                \textbf{Graphene and carbon nanotubes} are materials with extraordinary mechanical and electronic properties. High electron conductivity, linear energy dispersion and relatively long spin relaxation time make them good candidates for replacing silicon in low power electronics and spintronics.
                Our research focuses on spin-orbit interaction in carbon-based systems induced by adatoms, substrate or external fields. Starting from first principle calculations we develop realistic theoretical models describing the underlying physics.
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, take a look at my edited question.

Comment: @alex If you have too many centre environments to rewrite them, maybe you can redefine `\begin{center}` to make such a box? (if they are more then one line, one probably has to think a bit more first)

Answer (score 3):

It's a documented feature of `wrapfig` that it shouldn't be used near lists (and `center` is a list. In this case all you need is a blank line after `BBB` and it works, but I'd have simplified the markup a bit to:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.5]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
                \begin{center}

                    1

                    2

                    3
                \end{center}
                AAA
                \begin{center}
                    Nanophysics
                \end{center}
                BBB

                \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}
                \end{wrapfigure}
                \textbf{Graphene and carbon nanotubes} are materials with extraordinary mechanical and electronic properties. High electron conductivity, linear energy dispersion and relatively long spin relaxation time make them good candidates for replacing silicon in low power electronics and spintronics.
                Our research focuses on spin-orbit interaction in carbon-based systems induced by adatoms, substrate or external fields. Starting from first principle calculations we develop realistic theoretical models describing the underlying physics.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```